# Prevent user from dismissing Apple Pay's dialog PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow, applepay, presentviewcontroller

I'm adding PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController to my app. I present it, and after the payment method is authorized, I get the token at didAuthorizePayment method as expected.
At this point, I make an asynchronous call to my back-end server in order to make a transaction with the token, all this time the dialog should remain visible and the dialog's spinner is animated.
There is no way for me to disable user dismissing the dialog by tapping outside the dialog when it's presented and waiting for the back-end call to end. I can make some workaround and keep responding to that call even if the dialog is dismissed, but it's a very negative user experience.
I tried almost anything possible, setting isUserInteractionEnabled false to the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController's view, also adding overlay view didn't help (I gave it some color and it appears for a second), it seems like it natively taking control of any programmatic solution I find.

```
paymentVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)

public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
    // Trying to disable dismiss of the dialog from here or by calling the presenting ViewController to do it.
    
    // MyApiCall.request()
}
```

Comment: As a general rule you can't modify the behavior of views external to your application. When it comes to payment stuff it probably has even more safe-guards. Instead you should gracefully handle the user dismissing the view.

Comment: I strongly agree with you about "not messing with native behavior", but on the other hand it seems really strange to give a spinner whilst enabling users to dismiss it during the process, and from what I've read it is Apple's suggestion to process any back-end request while the spinner is animated. I was wondering whether someone encountered it, or found some solution of how to block the screen without interfering with the dialog itself.

Comment: @MaorAtlas did u find any way to prevent 'tap to cancel' while spinner is running?

Comment: @user3247895 No, no solution actually. The suggestion I got from Apple's representative is to show my own custom overlay (I can detect when it is being dismissed) and so I did. Working currently to present my workaround for that (as for other Apple Pay SDK issues I was facing)